# add new columns and fill with string in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a new column and fill with strings respectively to the number of rows I have.

I did

```
df['new column'] = ['open', closed']
```

but it did not match the number of indexes I have. What should I add to my script so the desired strings will appear respectively follows the number of rows in the data frame.

Thank you.

Comment: If there is e.g. 5, 10, 500 rows in df, what is expected output? Random values from `['open', 'closed']` ?

Comment: yes, but I expect 'open' and 'closed' would always come in pairs. Is it possible?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want solution working for pair or unpair length of rows you can use `map` by dictionary from list and `enumerate`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(5)})

L = ['open', 'closed']

df['new column'] =  (df.index % len(L)).map(dict(enumerate(L)))
print (df)
   a new column
0  0       open
1  1     closed
2  2       open
3  3     closed
4  4       open
```